# Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Animate/ Easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I spent hours to figure out what JavaScript function or CSS3 rules is making the smooth Dropdown function in [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/tBc7y/) but I couldnt figiure it out.

Then I tried to create my own `slideToggle` as:

```
$(function() {
    $('.selectopt').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

which is not as good as the above mentioned demo and there are some issue with it as it just slide down and up the `.dropdown-menu` ONLY if user clicks on the top of `.selectopt` and it doesn't care about losing focus or selected options!.
Considering all of these can you please let me know what is making the smooth slide and fade presentation of the `.dropdown-menu` in the demo? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's "fancy" fading using transition of 0.25s. on
>   `dropdown-menu`class.

The demo you mentioned is using external resources

[image]

looking at the code

```
$("select[name='herolist']").selectpicker({style: 'btn-primary', menuStyle: 'dropdown-inverse'});
```

you can see that it's using `.selectpicker()` which is coming from [Bootstrap select plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). The object passed `{style: 'btn-primary', menuStyle: 'dropdown-inverse'}` contains only css classes to style the dropdown menu which are contained in [Flat UI CSS](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/css/flat-ui.css). When the code is executed the underlying HTML is changed to

[image]

Class `dropdown-menu` contains the following rules

```
.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #f3f4f5;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

Conclusion: It's "fancy" fading using transition of 0.25s.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of external resources in the fiddle:

- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap.min.js
- flat-ui.css
- bootstrap-select.min.css
- bootstrap-select.js

As far as I can see, `flat-ui.css` is responsible for the fancyness.

I'd recommend adding all the external resources from the fiddle and when you're done with the dropdowns, try removing each one to see if any of them aren't used. In the fiddle they are all requered.